# 'float' object is unsliceable

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, anaconda

I'm trying to generate two classes of random 2D points, one having a mean of [1,1] and the other a mean of [-1,-1]. I have written a function but I get an error that can't figure out. I googled it but didn't find anything. Here's my function :

```
def gen_arti_Bis(nbex=10,centerx=1,centery=1,sigma=0.1,epsilon=0.02):
    xpos=np.random.multivariate_normal([centerx,centery],np.diag([sigma,sigma]),nbex/2)
    xneg=np.random.multivariate_normal([-centerx,-centery],np.diag([sigma,sigma]),nbex/2)
    data=np.vstack((xpos,xneg))
    y=np.hstack((np.ones(nbex/2),-np.ones(nbex/2)))
    return data,y
```

and here's the error message when I type gen_arti():

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-64-a173cf922dac>", line 1, in <module>
    gen_arti_Bis()
  File "<ipython-input-63-da8720093c11>", line 2, in gen_arti_Bis
    xpos=np.random.multivariate_normal([centerx,centery],np.diag([sigma,sigma]),nbex/2)
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 4308, in mtrand.RandomState.multivariate_normal (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:23108)
TypeError: 'float' object is unsliceable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3, division using the `/` operator always does floating point division, even if the numbers on both sides of the operator are integers. In several places you're computing `nbex / 2`, and passing the result as an argument where numpy expects an integer.

Specifically, `np.random.multivariate`'s last argument is supposed to be either an `int` or a `tuple` of `int`s. You're passing in a `float`, which it won't accept, even if the float's value is actually an integer (e.g. `5.0`). You're also passing a `float` to `np.ones`, but that function seems to handle it OK (it ignores any fractional part of the input number).

The most basic fix for this is to explicitly perform integer division using the `//` operator. Replace each place you have `nbex / 2` with `nbex // 2` and it should work as you intended it to.

Note that the integer division performed by `//` will always pick the floor value (i.e. it rounds down, towards negative infinity). If you want to round differently in some situations, you may want to do your division with `/` and then convert the float result to an integer with `round` (which will round a value that is half way between two integers to which ever one is even) or `math.ceil` (which will always round up).

Comment: Oh thanks a lot, it worked. But how did you know that this was the problem ? In fact, I didn't understand the meaning of the error message (unsliceable ?!). Could you explain it please ?

Comment: I just looked for places you might be passing a float where it was not expected. I suspect the numpy code has something that checks the type of the `size` parameter with `isinstance(size, int)` and it then falls back on code to handle a tuple. A tuple can be sliced (e.g. `tup[start:stop]`), and I guess the code tries it for any non-integer argument, leading to the exception about slicing a float.