# Issue with 'float' object, unsliceable?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to convert a column that contains date values which originally show as the type '20140701165829' to the date time format (which would be year=2014, month=07, day=01 in this case. However I am getting "'float' object is unsliceable" error even after performing integer division.

I've tried referencing ['float' object is unsliceable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29181051/float-object-is-unsliceable), rounding, playing with the division type, and running just this block of code (which works):
    (df.timestamp_first_active // 1000000)

To be fully and minimally testable, my data sources come from the following:
https://github.com/FraPochetti/Airbnb/blob/master/data/train_users_2.csv
https://github.com/FraPochetti/Airbnb/blob/master/data/test_users.csv

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
train_users = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/mmcgown/Downloads/train_users_2.csv")
test_users = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/mmcgown/Downloads/test_users.csv")
df = pd.concat((train_users, test_users), axis=0, ignore_index=True)
df['timestamp_first_active'] = pd.to_datetime((df.timestamp_first_active 
// 1000000), format='%Y%m%d')

---> 11 df['timestamp_first_active'] = 
pd.to_datetime((df.timestamp_first_active // 1000000), format='%Y%m%d')


--> 451             values = _convert_listlike(arg._values, True, format)

pandas\_libs\tslibs\strptime.pyx in 
pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime.array_strptime()

TypeError: 'float' object is unsliceable
```

Comment: I've used your files and your snippet code, but I cannot reproduce your error. I get a warning about sorting, but no error about float.

Comment: Maybe my error resides in how I copied and saved the csv? Could you provide the way to read csv directly from the site? I’ve imported url reader but it always times out waiting for host to reply. If it doesn’t work after that, it’d probably be my libraries.

Comment: I have linux, and I used from command line `wget urlofthefile`. There is a window version of wget [see here](https://superuser.com/a/25540) but other tools can be used too. Give it a try.

Comment: In the least interesting outcome, it turned out that the way I saved my excel after copying test_users.csv to it left the column as 2.01E13. Without converting this column's format to Number before saving the excel as csv, it chopped off the rest into certain dates that had year/month/00 or no day. In train_users_2 I had converted to Number just to see the values originally, but this hindered me from seeing it when concatenated since I was looking at the first few rows (and the error message isn't very descriptive for this case).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and I used `astype()` instead and it worked for me.  I would try:

```
(df.timestamp_first_active // 1000000).astype('datetime64[ns]')
```